# Is the expression 'the hardest work there is' an idiom you often use?

Tags: usage

I haven't encountered the phrase, so I just think ***there is*** means ***existing***.
How can I understand the structure ***noun + there is***?

> “Thinking is the hardest work there is, which is probably the reason
> so few engage in it.” - Henry Ford.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an idiom.  As you have guessed, this is a use of the [**existential *there***](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/existential-there-sentence-structure/), which basically means "existing", so the sentence is saying "Thinking is the hardest work *that exists*."

I think what might be confusing you is the structure, because it looks like "*noun* there is" is a single clause, but you need to parse it differently.  Think of it like

> X is the Y (that) *verb phrase*

*Y* can be a noun phrase, or a comparative adjective.  In your sentence, "there is" happens to be the verb phrase. For example,

> This is *the only one* (that) *we have*.
> That is *the woman* (that) *I saw*.
> It is *the last one* (that) *exists*.
> This is *the biggest* (that) *there is*.